# Getting error when used 'mvn -version' in command prompt

Tags: maven

following are the variable set by me:

user variables

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
PATH      : %JAVA_HOME%
```

system variables

```
JAVA_HOME.: C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07 
M2        :%M2_HOME%\bin
MAVEN_HOME:D:\STUDYY\JAVA\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.1
MAVEN_OPTS:Xms256m -Xmx512m
PATH      :C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

after setting all this I am getting

```
mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Can somebody help with this problem?

Comment: Your problem lies within your user and system variable setup. How to configure Windows properly is out of scope for stackoverflow. Instead, you should ask it on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt, use the whole path of mvn in quotes:

```
"C:\Program Files\maven\bin\mvn.bat"
```

Also, check that your %M2_HOME%, and other vars, have quotes if they have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the value where you setting for M2_HOME, set it properly then it work.

Set your M2_HOME like this :
M2_HOME=D:\STUDYY\JAVA\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.1

Then it shud work.